# run live-server command from windows batch command with argument

Tags: windows, batch-file

[image: When run from batch file][image: It doesn't work. compare with correct screen shot with command is run standalone.]Similar questions have been asked multiple times but I just could not get it to work. Please help.

Here is my batch file.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Congratulations! Your first batch file executed successfully.
cd "C:\JavaScriptCode\JavaScript\js-bootcamp\10notes-app-advJS"
ECHO %cd%
call live-server --browser=firefox
PAUSE
```

Problem :
I want to call live-server with --firefox-browser. But I am not able to find the solution to this issue.
call live-server works fine.

Please suggest us how I achieve it.

Comment: I have never used `live-server`  but just looking at the basic documentation you have the syntax wrong.  The help file states: `--browser=BROWSER`

Comment: If live-server is a `.js` file, or to be more precise, not a `.bat` or `.cmd` file, then the `Call` command is not needed or technically appropriate. Open a Command Prompt window, type `call /?` , press the `[ENTER]` key and read the usage information, it should tell you that it's for running batch files!

Comment: live-server --firefox=browser is command I am able to run in power shell and as well in command prompt. Screen shot when I run using Command Prompt.

Comment: Could you please clarify your issue. You've changed your command, from `--firefox-browser` to `--browser=firefox`, and posted an image of it working too, but your text body says you want to use, `--browser=firefox`, and your comment states that `--browser=firefox` does work in both `powershell.exe` and `cmd.exe`. What doesn't work as it should? My assumption is that potentially `live-server` is working with the first argument, which because its being passed through cmd.exe is `--firefox`, because the `=` character is treated as a delimiter.

Comment: Hi Compo, If I run live-server --browser=firefox on powershell.exe and cmd.exe, it works and open a localhost in firefox browser. But when I am try to execute same command from the batch file which I pasted above, it doesn't work. I need to call live-server with --browser=firefox. Call live-server works fine but as soon I add call live-server --browser=firefox, the webpage don't open. Attached an error I receice. I hope I am able to make my point clear now.

Comment: I've already explained to you what I think is happening @vineeshchauhan! The command line being passed to `live-server` is being split because `cmd.exe` treats the `=` character as a delimiter, and therefore omits it. _(live-server is receiving two arguments, the first is `--browser` and the second is `firefox`)_. The only potential things I can suggest is to see if the argument is accepted doublequoted. e.g. `live-server "--browser=firefox"` Other than that, the only suggestion I can make is to modify the way that live-server accepts its input, so that it omits surrounding doublequotes.